# How to enable terraform module only with a specific workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I define a provider containing modules.

I can call terraform apply at the provider level with two different workspace:

```
workspace list
  default
  wk-p1
* wk-p2
```

I would like the following module only to be launch when I use the workspace wk-1:

```
module "sync" {
  source = "./../test-modules/sync"

  workspace="${local.workspace}"
  entity = "${local.entity}"
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
module "sync" {
  if ("${local.workspace}" == "wk-p2") {
    source = "./../test-modules/sync"

    workspace="${local.workspace}"
    entity = "${local.entity}"
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/953

Comment: @a.moussa  are you able to achieve this ??

Comment: @karansharma not yet :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you could use the `terraform.workspace` variable in conjuction with the `count` directive

```
 count = (terraform.workspace == "wk-p2") ? 1 : 0
```

This way when the workspace is `wk-p2`, terraform will create an instance of the module.

On the other hand if it evaluates to false it will create `0` instances of the modules, meaning it will `not` create anything

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try with "count". Something like:

```
count = terraform.workspace == "default" ? 1 : 0
```